# detect differences between two stings in a panda column and copy them in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like the following but with multiple rows:

```
data= [['tom is good', 'tom is bad'], ['nick is good', 'nick is good'], ['juli is nice', 'juli is wise']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name1', 'Name2'])
```

I want to find the rows where there is a difference between sentences and only copy where there are different in another column like the following:

```
df. assign(difference= " ")

df.difference=  
["good"  -> "bad", Nan     Nan,"nice" ->  "wise"]
```

I have tried

```
index= np.where(df["Name1"]!= df["Name2"])
list_m= index[0].tolist()
```

but do not know how to just take the different words and not the whole sentence and how to copy them in the format I specified in another column.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach using `set`.

**Ex:**

```
data= [['tom is good', 'tom is bad'], ['nick is good', 'nick is good'], ['juli is nice', 'juli is wise']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name1', 'Name2'])
df['difference'] = df['Name1'].str.split().map(set) - df['Name2'].str.split().map(set)
print(df)
```

Use `symmetric_difference`

**Ex:**

```
df['difference'] = df.apply(lambda x: set(x['Name1'].split()) ^ set(x['Name2'].split()), axis=1)
```

Edit as per comment

```
df['difference'] = df.apply(lambda x: ["{} --> {}".format(x, y) for x, y in zip(x['Name1'].split(), x['Name2'].split()) if x != y], axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
          Name1         Name2       difference
0   tom is good    tom is bad   [good --> bad]
1  nick is good  nick is good               []
2  juli is nice  juli is wise  [nice --> wise]
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. how can I have both differences in the third column like: good -> bad

Comment: how can I have both differences in the third column like: good -> bad

Comment: `df['difference'] = df.apply(lambda x: set(x['Name1'].split()) ^ set(x['Name2'].split()), axis=1)` ?

Comment: thank you but it returns AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'split'", 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: are you using `df.apply` exactly as above?

Comment: this one actually worked sorry to ask again, but i really want the output to look exactly like this format and not a dictionary :good ->bad, is there a way of doing that

Comment: Thank you very much. is there a way of deleting the empty lists from the column?